# Cant print unicode sinhala words using MS SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I cant print sinhala words using this code. Here `FullName` is a sinhala word. I use MS SQL Server 2008. I can get correct result but I cant echo the sinhala words I get from the SQL query.

```
function FindName($serverName,$uid,$pwd,$databaseName,$conn){



    $tsql = "SELECT FullName  ,NameDenotedByInitials,SerialNo,PDID,GNDID,VSID FROM dbo.Voter WHERE National_ID_Number = '28105000V'" ; 
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn,$tsql);    
    if ( $stmt ) { // echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";    
             }     
     else {    
        echo "Error in statement execution.\n";    
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }   

     while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {  


     $this-> NameS = $row['FullName'];
     $this-> NameT = $row['NameDenotedByInitials'];
     $this-> Sirial = $row['SerialNo'];
     $this-> PDID = $row['PDID'];
         $this-> GNDID = $row['GNDID'];
     $this-> VSID = $row['VSID'];}    



     echo $this-> NameS;

}
```

Comment: Is it stored correctly in the database ?

Comment: can you show your output as well??

Comment: Yes, It store as nvarchar, and when I select sql in the database it review correctly

Comment: yes my out put show as ?????????